# Can SDIO cards be in a shared bus topology

Tags: embedded, sd-card

I know MMC cards can share a bus and it seems like it should work with SD/SDIO cards as well. However, I've found conflicting information on the web and the simplified specs at sdcard.org talk about doing the card identification using "each cards individual CMD line."

If I manage to assign two SDIO cards different RCA (addresses) by using some trickery with powering up in the right order or using some form of muxing, shouldn't I be able to use them on a shared bus?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Just to be clear; you are using an SDIO interface rather than SPI; is that my correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read and know of SDIO, you should be able to multiplex the CMD line to the cards and share the data lines. I don't believe the DAT lines will be used at all except in response to a command.

According to http://www.embeddedrelated.com/usenet/embedded/show/69909-1.php, one poster explains how the ALL_SEND_CID command works on a multicard bus. In this explanation, no lines are multiplexed. I'm not sure how the initialization sequence would work in this topology and it's not explained.

I know once the card is identified and given the relative address you can select and deselect the card for handling commands.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I've gotten it to work, sort of, since I posted the question. I'm "multiplexing" the CMD line by powering up the SDIO device I want to talk to, then when that's done I power up the other one. Once that's done the two devices coexist and I can select one or the other with the SELECT/DESELECT command. My situation is actually a little different since one of the devices is eMMC, the other is SDIO. I've seen my SDIO device respond to the "set card address" command even it it's been deselected so for two SDIO devices I'd probably need a proper bus mux.

Comment: Regarding the ALL_SEND_CID: it's a broadcast command in open-drain mode. All cards respond until they see a mismatch (they have a 1 but someone else has a 0) and the mismatching cards stop responding. The card with the most 0s wins and gets to talk to the host and gets an address and goes silent. The host repeats that cycle until everyone is squared away. Unfortunately, SD/SDIO didn't adopt that approach, for whatever reason.